# Linq Query Help on outter join against a list in and object

Tags: linq

I have the following object Job and Job sor are populated by reading in data from an XML file and Sor is populated from a database.

```
class Job
{
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }
    public string ClientReference { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public List<JobSor> JobSorList { get; set; }
}

class JobSor
{
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public string SorUserCode { get; set; }
    public string SorNotes1 { get; set; }
    public string SorNotes2 { get; set; }
}
class Sor
{
    [Key]
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string contract { get; set; }
}
```

I want to write a linq query that will show me all the JobSors that do not exist in the Sor object.

This is what I have so far but I can’t reference the SorUserCode property?

```
var db = new dbContext();

var sor = db.Sors.Where(p => p.contract == "??");

var query =
          from j in jobs
          join p in sor on j.JobSorList.SorUserCode equals p.code into jp
          from a in jp.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select j;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get list of all `JobSor` from `jobs` list.
Then apply condition `Where` its `SorUserCode` value does not match with `Any` `code` value of the `sor` list.

Your query will be as below.

`var query = jobs.SelectMany(x => x.JobSorList)
                .Where(x => !sor.Any(y => y.code == x.SorUserCode));`